# Counting occurrences of words using functional programming

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, python-itertools

## Task

Given a *list of strings* that may or may not have one or more words in them, how can I use fuctional programming to create a word-frequency dictionary? By functional programming, I'm explicitly referring to the use of `map`, `filter`, or `reduce`. Additionally, table-comprehensions also fall in the line of functional programming.

---

### Code

```
def count_individual_words(word_list):
    word_count = {x: y.count(x) for y in word_list for x in y.split()}
    return word_count

tweets = ["I am a cat", "cat", "Who is a good cat"]

for i,v in count_individual_words(tweets).items():
    print(i,v)

#Expected Output (dict)
# => {
# "I": 1,
# "am": 1,
# "a": 2,
# "cat": 3,
# "Who": 1,
# "is": 1,
# "good": 1 }
```

---

## Main Issue

The main issue presents itself when counting words that have more than one occurrence such as ***cat*** or ***a***. The issue is that, rather than adding one to the current word count, instead it just overwrites the word count with one. Thus, at the end, the dictionary I get shows that all the words only occur once.

I would highly appreciate any reference to using `map`, `filter`, or `reduce`, as I am curious how one could use any of those given functions to accomplish this task.

Comment: What is `word_list` ?

Comment: you need `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 3):

Basically this is what that `collections.Counter` is for. But if you want to create the dictionary by yourself you can use `defaultdict` function from collections module as well:

```
In [17]: from collections import defaultdict

In [18]: d = defaultdict(int)

In [20]: for sent in tweets:
             for word in sent.split():
                 d[word] += 1
   ....:         

In [21]: d
Out[21]: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 2, 'is': 1, 'good': 1, 'am': 1, 'I': 1, 'cat': 3, 'Who': 1})
```

One other way which is not that efficient would be using a list comprehension and dictionary comprehension:

```
In [36]: all_words = [i for sub in tweets for i in sub.split()]

In [37]: {word: all}
all        all_words  

In [37]: {word: all_words.count(word) for word in set(all_words)}
Out[37]: {'a': 2, 'is': 1, 'Who': 1, 'am': 1, 'I': 1, 'cat': 3, 'good': 1}
```

Doing this using a functional programming could be like following:

```
In [38]: unique = set(all_words)

In [39]: dict(zip(unique, map(all_words.count, unique)))
Out[39]: {'a': 2, 'is': 1, 'Who': 1, 'am': 1, 'I': 1, 'cat': 3, 'good': 1}
```

Comment: But that is not by using functional programming

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre For the sake of completeness just update.

Comment: okay, that is good. but as you said `Counter` is the best way, functional programming is not always the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

The most logical approach also uses functionnal programming but only to feed to `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections,itertools
collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.split() for x in tweets))
```

In case where you count/accumulate without using `Counter`, here's an alternate approach:

- generate a chained/sorted list of words
- group them and generate dictionary counting the occurrences

code:

```
import itertools

tweets = ["I am a cat", "cat", "Who is a good cat"]

words = sorted(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.split() for x in tweets)))
count = {k:len(list(v)) for k,v in itertools.groupby(words)}
```

result:

```
{'cat': 3, 'I': 1, 'Who': 1, 'is': 1, 'am': 1, 'a': 2, 'good': 1}
```

that could even be one-lined but readability would suffer

(note that `list` is forced in `sorted` to speed operations up)